# Error using Editable extension of Bootstrap-Table

Tags: jquery, x-editable, bootstrap-table

I am having some trouble using Editable extension of wenzhixin Bootstrap-table found at https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src/extensions/editable . I just decided to use this extension as I already use Bootstrap-table for other purposes in my project. When I used this Editable extension I get the following Console error on Chrome:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at BootstrapTable.initTable (bootstrap-table-editable.js:45)
at BootstrapTable.init (bootstrap-table.js:344)
at new BootstrapTable (bootstrap-table.js:126)
at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap-table.js:2202)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.$.fn.bootstrapTable (bootstrap-table.js:2179)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (bootstrap-table.js:2219)
at j (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I am unable to understand what could be the problem.I tried looking at the docs and examples at http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/ and https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/welcome.html .Additionally,I also went through issues on the github repository for Bootstrap-table examples  at https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/issues

Answer (score 1):

It may be because of version conflict.
Please try using the below css and js
https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css
https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.js
https://rawgit.com/fsauter/bootstrap-table/develop/src/extensions/editable/bootstrap-table-editable.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js